# How to use php docs correctly with inheritance?

Tags: php, phpdoc

In php docs, how do you put return type to return current class/object, instead of parent class? For method which is not overwritten in child class

```
class A { 
    /**
    * return "docs" 
    **/ 
    public give(){
        return $this;
    }
} 
class B extends A{}
```

what should I put instead of "docs" to make php doc work correctly for subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Check about {@inheritDoc} the inline mode.

Reference: https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/guides/inheritance.html

Comment: So I have to overwrite the method in child class?

Comment: I have never used the inline version. Just regular. I understood on the reference that you can reuse the parent doc but type new info for the override.